# Let $S = \{u_1,u_2,...,u_k \}$ be a subset of non zero vectors from $\Bbb R^n$. Now consider the two statements given below.

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

Let $S = \{u_1,u_2,...,u_k \}$ be a subset of non zero vectors from $\Bbb R^n$.
Now consider the two statements given below.

I. If $S$ is linearly dependent set in $\Bbb R^n$ then $u_k$ is linearly combination of $u_1,...,u_{k-1}$.

II. If $S$ is linearly dependent set in $\Bbb R^n$ then $k < n$

Which of the following statements is true.

1. I is true and II is false.
2. I is false and II is true.
3. Both I and II are true.
4. Both I and II are false.

My attempt:
Let$a_1,a_2,...,a_k \in \Bbb R$ not all zero such that $a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_ku_k =0$ without loss of generality, let $a_k \neq 0$. So $$a_ku_k = -(a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_{k-1}u_{k-1}) \\\implies u_k = -\frac{a_1u_1+...+a_{k-1}u_{k-1}}{a_k}.$$

So I is true.

We know that superset of linearly dependent set is linearly dependent and hence II is false.
I think that option 1 is true. Please help me if I'm wrong anywhere.

Comment: Why “without loss of generality?” You are trying to prove this for the specific $u_k,$ so you can’t rearrange to put the non-zero coefficient at index $k.$

Comment: In case, if $a_k = 0$ then I is false.

Comment: Well, you’d still need to prove it with an example.